# how to use preg_match?

Tags: php, flash

I put together a small email script in php to be used by flash. To make it more secure I've added a preg_match check to compare the referrer and a preg_match to prevent header injection.

For the referrer check I'm cheding against the $url variable. And it should only be true if it starts with the referrer url. So for example http://spambot.com/index.php?http://www.mysite.nl isn't allowed, but "http://www.mysite.nl" is. To do that is this the correct format?

```
//check start with string
if (preg_match("/^".$url."/",$result);
```

Got me a little confused since I want to check $result against the variable $url and not the string '$url'.

For the header injection protection: should this preg_match line do it?

```
//prevent header injection
if (preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST["sFrom"] ) || preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $$_POST["sEmail"] ) )
```

Below is the complete email script for further reference:

```
?php

//referrer: 
$url = http://www.mysite.nl

//check referrer
$result = stripos($url, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

//check start with string
if (preg_match("/^".$url."/",$result); 
{

//prevent header injection
if (preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST["sFrom"] ) || preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $$_POST["sEmail"] ) ) 
        {

if ($result === false)
{
die("error"); //bad referrer
}
else
{
//process the action

$sendTo = $_POST["sEmail"];
$subject = $_POST["sSubject"];

$headers = "From: " . $_POST["sFrom"] . "<noreply@mysite.nl>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . "<noreply@mysite.nl>\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-path: " . "<noreply@mysite.nl>";

$message = $_POST["sMessage"];

mail ($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);

}

}

}
?>
```

Comment: referers can be trivially forged. your referer check provides about as much as "security" as using a single piece of toilet paper to dry up a swimming pool.

Comment: Be that as it may: the way I wrote it, that would in theory check if $result begins the string put in $url?

Comment: no, it'll check if $url appears ANYWHERE in the refere. someone could trivially do `http://malicious_site.com?q=http://yoursite.com` and "pass"

Comment: So how do I check if it starts and only starts with http://yoursite.com? Isn't "/^" supposed to only allow $url to be at the start of the $result string?

Comment: Explode the headers by line and then loop them list($header, $value) = explode($header_line); and check if the header is in allowed headers array('to','from' ...).

Comment: Ok, will give that a try too. Buy in theory to check that a string starts with a string put in a variable $url and not literally '$url', that would be if (preg_match("/^".$url."/",$result); right? And to check if $url appears anywhere in the referrer if (preg_match("/".$url."/",$result);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it on Mamp and the use of preg_match to look for the string starting with $url was correct. The use of preg_match in the header injection needed some correction. Had to use !pregmatch on both occasions since the script should only continue when there weren't any newlines in the from and to fields.